# He wasn't who I confided in daily to vs He wasn't who I ranted daily to

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I would like to know the differences in meaning between the two phrases, in particular the former. Please note which phrase is more optimistic. Any alternatives to these phrases are also welcome (if they offer an optimistic perspective).

Comment: The difference in optimism, if you want to call it that, between "confide" and "rant" should be fairly straightforward; can you [edit] to clarify what you understand those words to mean? It would also help to know how you plan to use the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

They are both very different expressions, with very different undertones.

To **confide** in someone means to trust someone and share your secrets with them. Therefore 'He wasn't who I confided in daily' means he wasn't a person I trusted enough to share my innermost thoughts and secrets with.

To **rant** to someone, on the other hand, means to talk in a noisy, excited, or declamatory manner, usually expressing (at length) a complaint or negative opinion about someone or something. And it's generally implicit that the person on the receiving end is tolerating the conversation, rather than seeking it out. Therefore 'He wasn't who I ranted daily to' means he wasn't the person I'd complain to every day about something I didn't like. That *can* mean you didn't trust them enough, but it can also mean (and this is probably the more realistic reason) that their personality wouldn't tolerate it on a daily basis.

Both are negatives, and context plays a large role here so it's hard to say which one is more 'optimistic'. It also depends on whose perspective you are speaking from. 
But personally I'd prefer to be the person who people didn't rant to, than the person who people didn't confide in. But as mentioned in one of the comments, sharing the context of this discussion is really the only way for anyone here to tell you which one is more suitable.